# Question about Faddeev-Popov gauge-fixing in Schwartz textbook

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, gauge

I am trying to understand equation (25.91) from Schwartz's Quantum Field Theory textbook. The goal is to gauge-fix the path integral for Quantum chromodynamics using the Faddeev-Popov trick. Briefly, the argument boils down to multiplying the integral by:

$$1=C\sqrt{\det(\partial_{\mu}D^{\mu})^2}\int {\cal D}\pi~ e^{-i\int d^{4}x \frac{1}{2\zeta}(\partial_{\mu}D^{\mu}\pi-\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu})^2}$$ where $C$ is some numerical coefficient.

Now, in the second line of (25.91) the author redefines $$A\rightarrow A+ D\pi ,$$ where $D$ is the gauge covariant derivative in the adjoint representation. He claims that this shift results in the dependence of the integrand on $\pi$ dropping out leading to an extra factor $\int {\cal D}\pi$ which is not significant.

I do not understand how the shift $A\rightarrow A+D\pi$ leads to the expression in (25.91). Shouldnt we also shift the $D$ in the factor $\partial D \pi$ living in the argument of the exponential?

Comment: Please copy all relevant equations into your post. There is nothing more frustrating than a question that is not self-contained, without even a link to the pdf you are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

OP has a point. Ref. 1 transforms the integration variables$^1$
$$ A^b_{\nu}\quad\longrightarrow\quad A^{\prime a}_{\mu}~=~A^a_{\mu} - \partial_{\mu}\pi^a - gf^{abc} A^b_{\mu}\pi^c~=~A^a_{\mu} - D_{\mu}^{ab}(A)\pi^b$$
upstairs in the exponential function of eq. (25.91) but forgets to also transform the factor $\frac{1}{f[A]}$ downstairs. The result (25.93) is certainly the well-known correct result for the [Faddeev-Popov path integral](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Faddeev-Popov_ghosts) in [$R_{\xi}$-gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R%CE%BE_gauges), but the derivation$^2$ leading to eq. (25.93) is flawed. The Faddeev-Popov trick usually starts by considering an identity of the form "delta-function times determinant" rather than the identity $\frac{f[A]}{f[A]}=1$. A correct derivation is given in e.g. Ref. 2.

References:

1. M.D. Schwartz, [*QFT & the standard model*](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/), 2014; eq. (25.91).
2. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; chapter 71. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).

--

$^1$ Notice the minus sign. It should probably also be mentioned that the [change of integration variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) induces a [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)
$$ \det\frac{\delta A^{\prime a}_{\mu}}{\delta A^b_{\nu}}~=~\text{function of } \pi \text{ but not a function of }A,$$
which in principle has to be included in the path integral $\int\!{\cal D}\pi$.

$^2$ The corresponding abelian derivation in section 14.5 of Ref. 1 is fine because $f$ then doesn't depend on $A$.

Comment: Many thanks @Qmechanics . I do not understand why you do not consider how $D_\mu$ also change under this field definition? The covariant derivative $D$ is present in both the determinant and the argument of the complex exponential. So, we expect that these will change. No?

Comment: I mean, we expect that $det(\partial _\mu D_\mu) $ and that $\partial _\mu D_\mu \pi$ will also change under this field definition

Comment: I updated the answer.